# what's the difference between operators when used multiple re.FLAG

Tags: regex, python-3.x

there are 3 regex patterns, as bellow.

```
r1=re.compile(r"""
    # com
    abc
    # tehis
    \s+\d+
    """, re.S|re.X)

r2=re.compile(r"""
    # com
    abc
    # tehis
    \s+\d+
    """, re.S+re.X)  

r3=re.compile(r"""
    # com
    abc
    # tehis
    \s+\d+
    """, re.S&re.X)
```

and string to be matched is as fellow.

```
>>> s
'abc\n    899'
```

the search and match result is shown as bellow.

```
>>> s
'abc\n    899'
>>> r1.findall(s)
['abc\n    899']
>>> r2.findall(s)
['abc\n    899']
>>> r3.findall(s)
[]
```

we see r3 matched failed, while r1 and r2 successed. so what's the difference between different operators when used multiple re.FLAGS?

Answer (score 1):

The `re` flags, such as `re.I`, appear to be integer values.  But, they are intepreted as binary bit masks. 
 So, here is what your masks are actually equal to:

```
re.S | re.X = 80
re.S + re.X = 80
re.S & re.X = 0
```

Here is what the value `80` is in binary:

```
1010000
```

And here are the values for `re.S` (64) and `re.X` (16) in binary:

```
re.S = 1000000
re.X = 0010000
       1010000 <--- 80 in decimal
```

It should be clear from above that `re.S | re.X` and `re.S + re.X` happen to cover the bits from both flags, while `re.S & re.X` does not.  In this case, integer addition `+` and bitwise OR `|` generate the same result.